# Unpermitted parameters even though permitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, nested-forms

I know, that a lot of questions related to strong params have already been asked, but I'm facing a very strange behavior here. I have a model with nested attributes, permitted the right params (I checked for typos like a hundred times) and still get the error:

`Unpermitted parameters: :season_start, :season_end`

The strange thing about this: there is a third variable in the same nested model which gets accepted!

Here's my relevant code:

```
class Api::HotelsController < ApiController

  ...

  def hotel_params
    params.require(:hotel).permit(:id, :listing_name, ..., seasons_attributes:[:id, :season_start, :season_end, :period, :_destroy])
  end
end
```

And my Model:

```
class Hotel < ApplicationRecord

  ...

  has_many :seasons, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :seasons, update_only: true, allow_destroy: true

end
```

I have absolutely no idea what could be wrong and tried various things in order to solve the issue but I couldn't figure out, why `:period` is permitted but `:season_start` and `:season_end` are not.

Here's the log message of the received params:

```
"seasons_attributes"=>[{"period"=>"mid-season", "season_start"=>{}, "season_end"=>{}}]}
```

Comment: How're you planning to send the params?, within the `seasons_attributes`? why don't you try next the `:id` param?

Comment: Maybe in the submitted param`:season_start, :season_end` are not inside `seasons_attributes`?

Comment: Post the log message of the parameters received by the server for the request.

Comment: might be worth adding the code for the form view to your question so we can get an idea of what parameters are being submitted - quite likely the problem resides there.

Comment: Ok, so I just found out that for some reason it doesn't permit datetime format. So basically when I change the datepicker field to a regular input and submit something like "20171123" everything works as expected!

Comment: Still stuck here...I can't figure out what the issue is! When I submit a datetime with a datepicker ([vuejs-datepicker](https://github.com/charliekassel/vuejs-datepicker)) the params are unpermitted, but when I submit the datetime in the same format with an input field everything works perfectly fine.

Comment: Finally got the solution! Apparently the datepicker passed the value as a Date object. Basically I just needed to convert that Date object to a string.